# Execution results are different when I'm executing bash script directly and through sh

Tags: bash, sh, increment

I've a file new.sh

```
i=5
i=$[i+1]
echo $i
```

when I execute ./new.sh, it shows 6. But when I execute "sh new.sh", it shows

```
$[i+1]
```

as output. I just want to know why, and I need a code which will work on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Linux distributions use dash as their standard shell for scripts and therefore /bin/sh is only a symlink to /bin/dash, which is more lightweight, but lags some functionality compared with bash. Check that with:

```
ls -l /bin/sh
```

If you want to write POSIX compatible scripts, you should use foo=$n; $((n=n+1)) instead of foo=$((n++)) and foo=$((n=n+1)) instead of foo=$((++n)). The form $[] is deprecated and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The OS decides what type of file it is based on the first line.  Make it:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: `sh new.sh` overrides the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is different because when `bash` is run as `sh`, it turns off `bash`-specific features and hews more closely to the [POSIX shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) standard.

If you want your code to work the same under both `bash` and `sh`, you will need to write your code in the `sh` subset of the `bash` syntax.